# convert string to date and add days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a string in this format: yyyyMMdd
and i want to add a Year for every date in this format.
How can i do that?

Comment: which db you use ...?

Comment: @scaisEdge I forgot to mention that... :)
SqlServer 2014 management studio.

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server it should be

```
select  
    DATEADD(day, your_number_of_day, convert(datetime, your_date_column, 102))
from 
    your_table
```

Comment: And what if i need to convert it to yyyyMMdd after adding days?

Comment: If you have the string like you mentioned you must firts convert this to data and after add day ..otherwise  .. explain better ..

Comment: I have this format: yyyyMMdd, I need to add 365 days and then convert it once again  to yyyyMMdd..

Comment: the type of your column is a datetime or is varchar ..?  update your question with a real example  ..

Comment: @scaldesge
Just found out:
convert(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(day , 365, convert(datetime, myDate, 103)),112)
Ty!

Comment: well@user3885474  . if my answer is right .. or at least useful is fair mark it as accepted and rate is as useful ..

Comment: Adding 365 days is not always adding a year. a leap year is 366 days.